# Twilio, httplib2 'module' object has no attribute 'Http'

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, twilio, httplib2

On local host I am able to send a text message through Twilio.
On AWS I get the error "'module' object has no attribute 'Http'".

```
http = httplib2.Http( ...
    timeout=timeout,
    ca_certs=get_cert_file(),
    proxy_info=Connection.proxy_info(),
)
http.follow_redirects = allow_redirects
```

On my machine and on my ec2 instance, I have installed twilio in virtualenv with python3. When installing twilio, pip automatically installs httplib2 as a dependency. Does anybody know what the problem may be and how I can fix it? Thank you.

Comment: How do your import statements look, exactly?